# Why are two and three the only consecutive prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've learned that two *and* three are not only two consecutive numbers, but are also two consecutive *prime* numbers.  How is this possible?  I think I'm on the right track in the following text: The numbers two and three are prime numbers because they *both* have two factors: $1$ *and* itself and the other numbers divisible by two are all composite, so these are the only prime numbers that are consecutive.  Does this help you or am I on the right track?  Answer either of these questions, too, and I'd love to hear a shout from you about what you know!

Comment: Yes, one out of any two consecutive numbers is even. And there aren't so many even primes around.

Comment: Since There is a uniqe even  prime number !

Comment: Of course you mean " consecutive numbers that are prime", since consecutive prime numbers could be understood in the other way, like $7$ and $11$.

Comment: I mean "consecutive" prime numbers (split apart).  This means "prime numbers in order by counting numbers."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of every two consecutive numbers one will always be even. There is only one even prime number.

Whether there are an infinite number of pairs of primes which differ by two (the twin prime conjecture) is still open e.g. $3,5; 41, 43; 101,103$. A significant amount of progress has been made recently, but a new idea is likely to be required to crack the problem.

Comment: I'm not talking about twin primes; I'm talking about primes in order.

Comment: @Mathster I know, but I thought (or others who think of this question) might be interested. It goes to show how two similar looking questions can be very different in the resources required to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2 is the only prime even number, It's possible because the next even number, 4, is a composite number, as is every single even number after that because they are all evenly divisible by 2. Because of all the even numbers starting with 4 are composite, it's impossible to have two more prime consecutives. Or another way to say it is that when you identify a prime number, it's guaranteed that the number immediately preceding it, as well as the number succeeding it are going to be composite.

Answer (score -1):

2 and 3 are only consecutive prime numbers as 2 is the only even prime number and after that each consecutive pair contains one even and another odd number.